# Get first row in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get only the first row from this query. The query does not return the top row. Here is the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, age
FROM donates, persons
WHERE name = donor 
AND name IN (SELECT receiver FROM donates)
AND ROWNUM <= 1
ORDER BY age DESC;
```

When I run the query it returns `Chirs |35`.
Without the `ROWNUM <=1` this is what the table looks like.

```
NAME   |  AGE
-------------
george |  62
Chris  |  35
zara   |  24
```

Comment: if oracle 12c , you can using 'limit', look http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to get this is to use a subquery as the rownum is being looked at before the order by so:

```
select * from (
SELECT DISTINCT name, age
 FROM donates, persons
 WHERE name = donor 
 AND name IN (SELECT receiver FROM donates)
 ORDER BY age DESC
) where ROWNUM <= 1;
```

For a longer read look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `ROWID` rather than `ROWNUM` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ROWID = (SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM TABLE_NAME)
```

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT AT US

Comment: You may want to change ROWDIR to ROWID; For similar problems ROWID is better than ROWNUM

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the one with minimal age, so I suggest you to use the Min sql built-in function:

```
SELECT name, Min(age)
FROM donates, persons
WHERE name = donor 
AND name IN (SELECT receiver FROM donates)
```

It is a good practice to avoid rownum. And here you get a more semantic and efficient query.

Hope it helps,
Regards

Comment: This gives an error  `not a single-group group function` , you need a group by function